# RHadoop Map reduce job failed with the below error

Tags: rhadoop

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

Comment: Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="/home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CONF"="/home/hduser/hadoop/etc/hadoop")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_STREAMING"="/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.4.1.jar")
library(rhdfs) 
hdfs.init()
library(rmr2)
wc.map <- function(k,v){
 words.list = unlist(strsplit(v,'\\s'))
return (keyval(words.list,1))}
Reduce Function:wc.reduce <- function(k,v){
 return(keyval(k,sum(v)))
}
out <- mapreduce(input="/user/hduser/wordcount/wordcount_input.txt",
 output="/user/hduser/wordcount/output",input.format="text",map=wc.map,reduce=wc.reduce)

Comment: What RHadoop Map reduce job?  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's a map reduce job to determine wordcount of a text file.I am getting error in hadoop streaming. Not sure what the issue is ?